# Ionic-3 Avatar can't center

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am created `Ionic 3 Avatar`, and Im try to make it center but its cant center, I don't know why can't this center, please help me to fix this
Look my attached image, 
[image: Look at this image]

**html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-avatar class="avatars" >
    <img src="assets/imgs/pro-img.png">
  </ion-avatar>
</ion-content>
```

**css**

```
.avatars{
   margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: does my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the `.avatars` class to `img` tag or use this css

```
.avatars img{
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here the way to make something to be in center:

```css
.main {
  width : 100%;
  background-color : #000;
}
#element {
  background-color : #F00;
  width : 50px;
  height : 50px;
}
.center {
  margin : 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div id="element" class="center"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Last answers were incomplete.

an inline example:

```
    <ion-avatar slot="start" style="background-color: #00212E;">
        <img src="../../assets/icon/transfer.svg" style="height: 70%; width: 70%; margin: 15% auto; display:block">
    </ion-avatar>
```

the 'display:block;' will let you center the image.
setting size in % will allow you to set the margin correctly.

result:
[centered image in an ion-avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY2tt.png)